# Finding a xpath for text which is followed by break tag

Tags: xpath

I have below HTML code, in that I have to come up with XPath for the 2nd line of text: "Policy Count - 0".

```
<h2 id ="lblpremiumVol">
"Premium Volume - $"
<br>
"Policy Count - 0"
</h2>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: add the actual html , its not possible to tell without seeing the actual html structure

Comment: <h2 id = "lblpremiumVol">
"Premium Volume - $"
<br>
"Policy Count - 0" </h2>

Comment: Can any one help me in this

Answer (score 4):

Your xpath would be `//h2/text()[2]`. See the test [here](http://xpather.com/p3Pvk7HZ).

**P.S.** - I have no idea why you need that xpath (since you're not mentioning that in your question) but as a side note: you will not be able to use this xpath with Selenium since Selenium cannot wrap a text node into a `WebElement`

If you need that for Selenium, use the following approach:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.evaluate('//h2/text()[2]', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ).stringValue;");
```

Comment: thanks it works

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct

Comment: but while running the scripts it throws an error, actually we have to compare two values which is equal or not(i.e, for one value i got a xpath and the other one is above)

Comment: Which script? Which error? What did work?

Comment: @user45674 I think you need to raise another question because there are the details which have not been originally mentioned.

Comment: No it doesnt work